# How is The Number of Self-Intersections of a Compact Connected Riemann Surface Embedded in a Complex Surface defined?

Tags: surfaces, riemann-surfaces, intersection-theory, complex-manifolds, transversality

**Complex Algebraic Foliations**, Book by **A. Lins Neto** and **Bruno Scárdua**, Chapter **3**, Page **82**.

Let $M$ be a **Complex Manifold** of complex dimension **two** (i.e., $M$ is a **Complex Surface**).

Let $S$ be a **Compact Connected Riemann Surface** (the complex dimension of $S$ is **one**) such that $S$ is **Embedded** in the complex manifold $M$.

We aim to define the **Number of Self-Intersections** of the Riemann Surface $S$.

I have some questions:

1. What do they exactly mean by saying "Let $\widetilde{S}$ be a $C^{\infty}$ deformation of $S$"?
2. Does "$\widetilde{S}$ cuts $S$ transversely" mean that for every point $p \in S \cap \widetilde{S}$ we have $T_p(S) + T_p(\widetilde{S}) = T_p(M)$?
3. what is the "isotopy of $S$"?
4. Why is $S \cap \widetilde{S}$ finite?
5. what do they mean by saying "a basis $\{u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2\}$ is positive in $T_p(M)$?

[image]

Comment: This is way too many questions for one post. Besides, there is one key question you are not asking, namely, why this intersection number is independent of the perturbation of $S$. I suggest, you read the book by Guiillemin and Pollack "Differential Topology" through Chapter 3 ("Oriented intersection"), where all these notions and results are explained in great detail. (The authors of the book you are reading expect you to be familiar with basic notions of differential topology.)

Comment: @MoisheKohan thank you so much. I would be very grateful if you were able to check out my newest questions.